# What is the simple reason why there is no simple solution to a system of quadratic equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, multilinear-algebra

Let's consider a system of $n$ equations and $n$ real unknowns $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik} x_k = B_i, \qquad \text{with } i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$$

The solution of which exists as long as the determinant $A = \det(A_{ij})$ is not zero. However, the seemingly innocent second-order system given by:

$$\sum_{j,k} A_{ijk} x_j x_k + \sum_j B_{ij}x_j + C_ i = 0, \qquad \text{with } i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$$

It seems to have no general solution, I wonder two things:

1. There is something similar to the discriminant $\Delta$ of a quadratic equation that tells me something about the set of solutions (in the case of an unknown the discriminant informs me whether there are one, two, or no real solutions).
2. What is the simple reason why there is no simple procedure to find solutions to a system of quadratic equations?

Comment: 1. Consider the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of two (quadratic, or other) polynomials. 2. Quadratic equations are as hard as general systems of polynomial equations.

Comment: They’re… more complicated? I’m not sure, it sounds like you expect quadratics to remain simple but even in the univariate case we have to do something weird.

Comment: One challenge is that your system of $n$ quadratics can have $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $\cdots$, $2^n-2$, (maybe $2^n-1$), $2^n$, or infinitely many solutions.  So anything like a discriminant has to indicate up to $2^n+2$ different states.  (Example for $2^n$ solutions: $\{x_i(x_i-1)=0 \mid i \in [1,n] \subset \Bbb{Z}\}$.  And this is a "simple" example.)